# JSF Table Column Widths using CSS Not Working

Tags: css, jsf, css-tables

I am applying styling to the column widths in a JSF 1.2 table and my problem is that I can see the style applied but it doesnt seem to be controlling the width at all.

Here is the stylesheet.css:

```
.col1 { background:#FF0000; width: 1000px; }
.col2 { width: 100px; }
.col3 { width: 50px; }
.col4 { width: 200px; }
.col5 { width: 100px; }
.col6 { width: 50px; }
.col7 { width: 200px; }
.col8 { width: 100px; }
.col9 { width: 50px; }
.col10 { width: 200px; }
.col11 { width: 100px; }
```

Here is the JSF xhtml:

```
    <h:dataTable id="pcTable" 
        styleClass="table-background"
        rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row" cellpadding="3"
        columnClasses="col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11"
        headerClass="table-header" var="decorator">
```

In Chrome the column appears red per the style background #FF00000 but the width is still small and seems to just autofit content, so obviously its picking up the CSS.

If I inspect the column element in Chrome I can see this:

.col1 {
    background: #FF0000;
    width: 1000px;
}

What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to the table's `.table-background` properties.  If it works, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @cobaltduck Ok, well that at least did something - it set all the columns to be the same exact width, it then cuts off the text for the stuff that is too wide rather than word-wrap.   i need to be able to tell it to be x-width, and word-wrap if it doesnt fit

Comment: @cobaltduck It seems like I am getting some mixed success with a combination of table-layout, width, and word-wrap on the Table styling rather than trying to style the columns ....  Ill post back if I get sucess

Comment: Alright so it seems like I need to have on the table-background:  width set, word-wrap: break-word, and also the .col1 to .col11 set for this to work.